# How to modified object of child viewcontroller from parent viewcontroller from in swift

Tags: swift, object, viewcontroller

I want to modify an object of child `UIViewController` but it is not working. Can anyone solve my problem? thanks a lot ~~

below is my code

My `ViewController` class:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    var x:UIView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var sec = second()
        sec.x?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view.addSubview(sec.view)
        self.addChildViewController(sec)

    }

}
```

My `second` class:

```
class second:UIViewController{

    var x:UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        x = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(55, 55, 100, 100))
        x!.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.view.addSubview(x!)

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the changes in the second `UIViewController` and then segue over to it? If so, you could override the `prepareForSegue` method inside of your `ViewController` class. Also, it may have been just for demonstration purposes, but I recommend classes with more intuitive names. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the view is probably nil when you are attempting to set its background color. Just add a background color property inside the second view controller and set that. Then inside viewDidLoad set the second view controller's background color from there.
Something like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    var x:UIView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var sec = second()
        sec.backColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view.addSubview(sec.view)
        self.addChildViewController(sec)
    }
}
```

And then:

```
class second:UIViewController {
    var backColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    var x:UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        x = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(55, 55, 100, 100))
        x.backgroundColor = backColor
        self.view.addSubview(x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After initializing second view controller, call `addChildViewController(instanceOfSecondVC)`
And after adding it as subview, call `sec.didMoveToParentViewController(self)`.
So your code will be like:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    var x:UIView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var sec = second()
addChildViewController(sec)
        sec.x?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view.addSubview(sec.view)
        self.addChildViewController(sec)
sec.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    }

}
```